# How to find source code language from a class object?

Tags: java, scala, kotlin

I'm writing a custom JUnit runner that will have to collect some metadata for the test case under execution. At execution time, we access the test case object via reflection getting a `Class` object. This runner will be used in Scala, Java, and Kotlin test suites. How do I find which was the source code language that gave origin to a given `Class` object?

Comment: Educated guess: you can't.

Comment: Compiled to jvm byte code. The artefacts that an object's class has in Scala and Kotlin. Try it out in a debugger. Also the .class file could have artefacts: `javap`.

Comment: passing some kind of additional arguments at the beginning of the test execution is also a good idea

Comment: Yeah, I think we will go with an extra VM argument to disambiguate

Comment: @GyroGearless Wrong guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Scala, you can check if the class is annotated with `scala.reflect.ScalaSignature` or `scala.reflect.ScalaLongSignature`. Kotlin uses [`kotlin.Metadata`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-metadata/index.html) for the same.